# Azure Logic Apps connectors for Azure Billing and reservations

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-billing-api

I tried to search in the standard connectors if there was something related to the Billing and Reservations APIs but nothing is there. Do I need to create a customer connector?

Answer (score 1):

Look through all of the logic app connectors, it seems not exist a connector to help you implement Billing and Reservations apis. So we can't do it by off-the-shelf connector in logic app.

Of course you can create a customer connector as you mentioned, but if you just want to request the api in logic app, you can do it by "[HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action)" action easily.

Comment: You can request this at https://aka.ms/costmgmt/feedback so this bubbles up in our prioritization.